# xpath with rvest fails, returning an empty list

Tags: web-scraping, rvest

I got stuck when using "rvest" to extract the COVID data from the page: https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus-interactive/index.html

Thanks for your time!

Here is my code:

```
library("rvest")

url = "https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus-interactive/index.html"

tbl <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="viz030_widget5_table"]') %>%
  html_table(fill=TRUE)
tbl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is dynamically retrieved. You can retrieve the required data in json format from

https://www.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/Content/CoronaViewJson_01/US_MAP_DATA.json

You can find this in the network tab when refreshing the original page.

```
library(jsonlite)

data <- jsonlite::read_json('https://www.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/Content/CoronaViewJson_01/US_MAP_DATA.json') %>% 
        .$US_MAP_DATA
```

Comment: Thank you, QHarr! I did do that before. It worked. I would like to try the way of extracting csv data table not embedded in HTML. The data are also downloadable directly. I am just curious if the json is not available.

Comment: Perhaps I am not understanding The data is not present in the html returned from the original url. You need to make a request similar to the above. You can then loop the returned structure to construct a table/df and write to csv.

Comment: Hi QHarr! I just found the url you provided was not the same as I used for a json data. How did you get it? Thanks!

Comment: Examine the network tab for the new xhr request made when you click the csv download icon - probably easiest way. You need to have network tab open at same time.

Comment: Got it. Thank you, QHarr!